# Git change master origin/HEAD and origin/master

Tags: git, github, git-branch, tortoisegit

In my Git repo I have a regular set of commits. However the last four commits were just some prototype code that should actually have been a branch. How can I go back to a previous commit and put that prototype code on to it's own branch.

In TortoiseGit I see something like this at the head.

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
                         |
                       master
                     origin/master
                     origin/HEAD
```

What I want is:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
          |              |
        master       proto_branch
     origin/master
     origin/HEAD
```

And then when I work off the C branch that is all the head and we can merge the `proto_branch` in to the main stream later. So that it will look like this if I were to keep committing.

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F
          |              |
          G              I
          |              |
          H          proto_branch
          |
        master
     origin/master
     origin/HEAD
```

Answer (score 5):

First create a new branch `proto_branch` from your current HEAD (you should be on master):

```
git branch proto_branch
```

Now you've both `master` and `proto_branch` at `F`.

Now to move `master` to commit `C`, do a `reset --hard`. Again you should be on `master` branch. Note that you should not have any local modification before doing hard reset. If present, stash them first.

```
git reset --hard C
```

And then to move `origin/master` to this commit, do a `force-push`:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: @0x499602D2: yes.  That would leave the work-directory unmodified (avoids the need to `git stash` but also leaves you in a peculiar situation: you're on branch master but set up as if you are on branch `proto_branch`).  If you want to go that way, it's probably best to start with `git checkout -b proto_branch` as the first step.

Comment: Worked perfectly and saved my butt. Thanks!